# How to disable all Gnome 3 notifications?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, gnome3, gnome-shell

A pop up shows up at the bottom on the screen in Gnome 3, when ever there are software updates or when I plug in an USB device.

I have disabled notifications in the menu in the top right corner, bit I still get them.

How do I disable those? Especially the one about software updates.

Answer (score 2):

I have several systems that I don't want update or other messages. I would prefer to just check logs. Unless you want to go into each program (i.e. Network settings » Disable Notifications), yet still get system messages.

You could:

```
su -
chmod 000 /usr/libexec/notification-daemon
reboot
```

This should work on most GNOME3 systems but kills all messages.